# Edit HTML Email template at run time in .net code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, system.net.mail

I below code is to send email by reading the template html, and it works fine. But now my question is how to pass Salutation customerName from my .net code to the template at run time.

```
 StringBuilder strBlr = new StringBuilder();
            string strHTML = string.Empty;
            string strTempalteHtmlpath = string.Empty;

            //create the mail message
            MailMessage mail;

 string strFrom = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["fromAddressForBT"];
                string strSubject = "Thanks for choosing Email contact preference";
                mail = new MailMessage(strFrom, customerDetails.EmailId);

                mail.Subject = strSubject;

                //Read Html Template File Path
                strTempalteHtmlpath = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TemplatePath"]);
                strHTML = File.ReadAllText(strTempalteHtmlpath);
                strBlr = strBlr.Append(strHTML);
                mail.Body = strBlr.ToString();
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


                //first we create the Plain Text part
                AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBlr.ToString(), null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBlr.ToString(), null, "text/html");

 mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
                mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

                //send the message
                SmtpClient smtpMail = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["smtpClient"]);
                smtpMail.Send(mail);

                mail.Dispose();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is code for sendemail button**

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Sendpage.htm"));
    string body = sr.ReadToEnd();         
    sr.Close();          
    body = body.Replace("#NameFamily#", txtNameFamily.Text);     
    body = body.Replace("#Email#", txtEmail.Text);        
    body = body.Replace("#Tellphone#", txtTellphone.Text);   
    body = body.Replace("#Text#", txtText.Text);       
    body = body.Replace("#Date#", DateTime.Now);        
    string Time = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());    
    body = body.Replace("#Time#", Time);        
    SendMail("email that you want to send to it", body);
```

**this is sendmail function code:**

```
 private void SendMail(string To, string Body)
    {
        SmtpClient Mailing = new SmtpClient("mail.domain.com");
        MailMessage Message = new MailMessage();
        Message.From = new MailAddress("mail@domain.com", "Your name or company name");
        Message.Subject = "Subject";
        Message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        Message.Body = Body;
        Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
        Mailing.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential MyCredential = new NetworkCredential("mail@domain.com", "password");
        Mailing.Credentials = MyCredential; Mailing.Send(Message);
    }
```